# Can't connect to phpMyAdmin database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am hosting a local database that I am having trouble connecting to. I have everything set up through MAMP. I know that my db user, pass, name, and host variables are correct, and I went into my Windows firewall to open up the TCP ports ingoing and outgoing. However, I am still getting the following message when I run the code below:

```
Connect failed: 2003
```

Does anyone know what this error number means? Below is the php code I am trying to run.

```
<?php
$db_user = 'db';
$db_pass = 'dbpass';
$db_name = 'dbname';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_errno);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: try using $mysqli->connect_error instead of errno (error number) it will state that it can't connect to the specified server... which tools have you tested your credentials with? phpmyadmin at least or some other external tools? maybe a typo... which version of php are using? is the mysqli library added? (check your phpinfo() on mysqli)

Comment: can you confirm that you are able to connect to the server through mysql client (in terminal)?

Comment: @Jigar I'm able to get into the db through MAMP to add/edit rows & tables, I just cant get to it when I run my php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP localhost,Under MYSQL tab, check "Allow network access to MySQL" and checkd "only from this Mac" and it may solve

Comment: Where do I find the MYSQL tab? Is it in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by some typographic error, thus I am voting to close it. But as it never takes enough votes to actually close a question, I feel I have to add an explanation for the future visitors: accepted answer can never solve anything, as mysql_connect is just an alias for the mysqli::__construct(). Thus, it just can't be when mysqli_connect works while new mysqli doesn't.